# Line integral: find intersection for surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find work for a particle moving through vector field $\boldsymbol{F} =x^2 \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} - yx \boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}$ in the positively oriented curve in the first quadrant in: $x=0$ ($yz$ plane); $y=x^2$ (parabolic cylinder); $x^2+y^2=1$ (cylinder). 
I got my 3 sections of the curve parameterized as $C_1=\langle\cos(t), \sin(t)\rangle$; $C_2=\langle t^2, t \rangle$; $C_3=\langle t, 0\rangle$.

However, I'm having trouble founding boundaries for $t$. I need to find the intersection of these curves, so I set up: $y=x^2$; then $x^2+x^4=1$ but I'm not sure where to go from there to get the $x$, $y$ values to find my intersection.

Comment: $x^4 + x^2 - 1 = 0$ is equivalent to $y^2 + y - 1 = 0$ which is a quadratic equation

Comment: Thank you. From that I got that $y=(-1+\sqrt(5))/2$ and then $x=\sqrt((-1+\sqrt(5))/2)$. Using that in my circle parameterization, I got $\cos(t)=\sqrt((-1+\sqrt(5))/2)$ and $\sin(t)=(-1+\sqrt(5))/2$, which yields $t=0,67$. However, I'm not sure how to convert that number now... I want to say that t goes from $0,67$ to $\pi / 2$. Is my 0,67 a degree that I need to convert to radians? A 0,67 degree angle sounds weird here...

Comment: The unit depends on which setting your calculator is on. Looking at the graph of the two curves, it's unlikely the angle is $0.67^\circ$

Comment: Right, I also thought it unlikely, but that's what I got from solving the quadratic equation. Where have I gone wrong? I solved the equation for y, used that in $y=x^2$ to get the value of $x$ and used those $x, y$ values to solve for $t$ in my circle parameterization.

Comment: I'm saying the answer is in radians, not  degrees

Comment: Oh, I see! That makes sense! Thank you!